# Repeated nested game objects (UnityEngine.GameObject.gameObject)

Tags: unity

I created a `UnityEngine.GameObject` and inspect its properties while in debug mode.

```
GameObject obj = new GameObject();
```

When I inspect the object, it has a property hierarchy similar to:

```
active:true
activeInHierarchy:true
..
gameObject:New Game Object (UnityEngine.GameObject)
    active:true
    activeInHierarchy:true
    ..
    gameObject:New Game Object (UnityEngine.GameObject)
      active:true
      activeInHierarchy:true
      ..
      gameObject:New Game Object (UnityEngine.GameObject)
```

If I execute, something like, in a debugger console:

```
new UnityEngine.GameObject().gameObject.gameObject.gameObject;
```

it would still return the same `New Game Object`.

Is the problem in my debugger or Unity? I'm using Unity 2018.4.11f1.

Answer (score 3):

`.gameObject` returns the current GO. This is the intended behaviour.